# Joomla replacement tags

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I am trying to implement this joomla plugin to replace `{twitter}demo_user{/twitter}` and `{facebook}demo_user{/facebook}` by links in some content.

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Access Deny');
class plgContentSocial extends jplugin
{
    function onContentPrepare($context, $article, $params, $limit)
        {
            preg_match_all('/{twitter}(.*?){\/twitter}/is', $article->text, matches)
            $i=0;
            foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
                $twitter_username=$matches[1][$1];
                $article->text=str_replace($match, '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_username.'"follow me on twitter</a>', $article->tex)
                $i++
            }
            preg_match_all('/{facebook}(.*?){\/facebook}/is', $article->text, matches)
            $i=0;
            foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
                $facebook_username=$matches[1][$1];
                $article->text=str_replace($match, '<a href="http://facebook.com/'.$facebook_username.'"follow me on facebook</a>', $article->tex)
                $i++
            }
        }
}
?>
```

My problem is: how can I use something like `{social type=twitter}demo_user{/social}` and `{social type=facebook}demo_user{/social}` ? I don't want to repeat the `preg_match_all` for every social network. Is there a way to achieve it?

Thank you very much for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the manual first. This is a very basic regular expression issue.

Use the following regular expression.

```
'/{social type="(facebook|twitter)"}(.*?){\/facebook}/is'
```

You would have to change then

```
 $type=$matches[1][$1];
 $username=$matches[2][$1];
```